# How come I can set default argument values but no a new object in php?

Tags: php, function, object

For example I have the following:

```
public function foo($integer = 1; $myObj = new myClass()){}
```

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in C:\xampp\htdocs..."

Comment: because its not valid php - what else to say?

Comment: you can set it as `myClass $myObj`, just like the answer below, so that you can pass an instance of that class in your argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function prototype has to be evaluated at compile time. There's no way to know what `new myClass` is until you're in the runtime, because we need the definition of the class and all of its ancestors to be able to build it plus any additional runtime information required to do so.

You can still set the default argument in your function though so that the assignment is deferred to the runtime.

```
class myClass {
    public function foo($integer = 1, myClass $myObj = null) {
        if (!$myObj) {
            $myObj = new myClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Also note you have a syntax error in your function prototype. The argument separator is a comma `,` and not a semicolon `;`.